# How to assign NULL to a pointer in unsafe code?

Tags: c#, pointers, null, unsafe

Please, can anybody tell me how to assign null to a pointer in this type unsafe code example...

```
public  struct Chunck
{
            unsafe
           public tag *start;
            unsafe
           public tag *end;

}

class  HeapManager
{
    public int HeapMemorySize = 1000;
    public int sizeAllcated = 0;
    unsafe
    Chunck *Header;
    HeapManager()
    {
        unsafe
        {// this is not happening as compare to C langauge its allowed ??
            Header =(Chunck*) NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language should this be?

Comment: I'd take a strong guess this is C#

Answer (score 3):

It couldn't be simpler

```
Header = null;
```

Comment: Oh sorry hahahah It was simple example i post actually I was assigning a nested pointer (linklist next and prev) but i dint use *next and *prev (*) was missing lolzz i didnt see it thanks problem solve hahahha sorry bro such a fool i m..........

Answer (score 2):

Just don't bother.  Unlike the C runtime, the CLR promises to zero-initialize all fields of a class when it is created.  Which automatically makes the Header member null.

Don't write heap managers in C#, please.